# select 10 rows forwards and 10 backwards from a date

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm trying to select 10 rows from today's date in either direction (forward and backwards in time) and in date order. The best I've got so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE dt >= now() ORDER BY dt ASC LIMIT 10
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE dt < now() ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 10
) ORDER BY dt ASC;
```

Is there a nicer/more efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: the `order by` clause must be included in both subqueries.

Comment: I just noticed that as well and added it! Thanks

Comment: without more knowledge of the dataset inner logic, I don't think you can get better than that.

Comment: besides, if there is an (ordered) index on `dt`, the query will be pretty fast for only 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is sound, but this is the correct query for it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE dt >= now() ORDER BY dt ASC LIMIT 10) A
    UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE dt < now() ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 10) B
) C
ORDER BY dt ASC;
```

Only one `ORDER BY` clause is permitted per level of query, so you actually need to further subquery the `A` and `B` parts shown. Also, UNION ALL avoids a sort operation, since you know the two sets are distinct.

An index on `foo.dt` will ensure that this query is as fast as can be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of you can use **simple** `query`

```
(SELECT * FROM one WHERE dt >= now() ORDER BY dt ASC LIMIT 10)
    UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM one WHERE dt < now() ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: That's not going to return the rows in the correct order is it?